# npm scripts not working as intended

Tags: npm

I'm trying to use npm scripts as below:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
    "prestart": "json-server --watch db.json",
    "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -o -c-1"
  },
```

I want to use `prestart` (json-server) before running `start` (http-server). But I'm only able to run one at a time. If I type `npm start` only `json-server` runs. Is it possible to run two servers in single command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
    "start-json": "json-server --watch db.json",
    "start-http": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -o -c-1",
    "start": "npm run start-json & npm run start-http"
  },
```

Now `npm start` will run `start-json` and `start-http` concurrently.

Comment: Is json-server trying to listen to the same port as http-server?

Comment: FWIW, one of the commands will be running in the background, so you may not see any output from it.

Comment: Works, thanks. Something was keeping existing port busy. Changed it and works like charm. Thanks mate.

Comment: Quick question, is there any difference between && and & ?

Comment: & is a shell operator to indicate that the preceding command should be forked as a background process. && is nothing, really, as far as I know in this context.

Comment: I would have thought that && waits for the first to finish successfully before launching the second. Works on the command line but havent' tried it with npm scripts.